# Define Select statement as variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

is it possible to define a **select** statement as variable, somethings like this:

> Define (Select t1.id, t1.var1, t1.var2, t2.id, t2.var1, t2.var2  From
>   table1 t1, table2 t2 Where t1.id = t2.id) as namevariable

Thanks for your help,
Andrea

Comment: It would be useful to know what you are trying to achieve and where it is being scripted (SQLPlus ?). Your example seems to suggest you want 6 values from a query to become the 'namevariable' which seems a little strange.

Comment: Maybe what you need is a [cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#GUID-F1FE15F9-5C96-4C4E-B240-B7363D25A8F1). There are various kinds, so it would be helpful to know what you need it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Define (Select t1.id, t1.var1, t1.var2, t2.id, t2.var1, t2.var2 From
>   table1 t1, table2 t2 Where t1.id = t2.id) as namevariable

You can do it as :

```
 DECLARE
   var   VARCHAR2 (100);
   v_emp_id   number;
BEGIN
   --Defining as a variable in PLSQL 
   var := 'Select employee_id from employee where employee_id = :1';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var into v_emp_id using 1 ;

   --Showing the result
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_emp_id);

END;
```

Comment: I don't understand the part:

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var into v_emp_id using 1 ;

Comment: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` we use to run dynamic queries in PLSQL block. This would switch PLSQL engine to SQL engine and i used `using` clause to pass the variable to where clause. Read more here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm

Comment: sorry is still unclear for me why you define v_emp_id and is used iside the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.. consider that I am new in slq..

Comment: I already answered your query above and shared a link for self study. Read it, Also `v_emp_id` is a variable to hold the result of the query. Its a variable. I guess you really need to know basics of PLSQL.. A good book may help

Answer (score 0):

simply with select ... into ...

```
DECLARE
    my_id NUMBER;
    my_val VARCHAR2(32);
BEGIN
    SELECT t1.id, t1.val into my_id, my_val from my_table t1 where... ;
END;
```